# jQuery select array from data attributes

Tags: arrays, string, html, parameters, nouislider

I'm trying to give an array to my makeSlider function.
The HTML5 Data attribute selects the correct array. Unfortunately, it is not interpreted as an array.

It does not work:

```
 values = $(this).data("slider");
 makeSlider(sliderID, targetID, values);
```

Is working:

```
makeSlider(sliderID, targetID, dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft);
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="noui-slider" id="slider-1" data-slider="dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft">
      <!-- slider here -->
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-md-up">
      <!-- Store selected value -->
      <input class="form-control slider-value" id="input-target-1">
    </div>
```

JS (script.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // slider array

    // Matrix 1
    var dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft = [{
      id: 1,
      value: "sehr wichtig"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: ""
    }, {
      id: 3,
      value: ""
    }, {
      id: 4,
      value: ""
    }, {
      id: 5,
      value: "unwichtig"
    }, {
      id: null,
      value: "weiß nicht"
    }];

    // Matrix 2
    var dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixRight = [{
      id: 1,
      value: "in hohem Maße"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: ""
    }, {
      id: 3,
      value: ""
    }, {
      id: 4,
      value: ""
    }, {
      id: 5,
      value: "in geringem Maße"
    }, {
      id: null,
      value: "weiß nicht"
    }];

  // build slider

  var makeSlider = function(sliderID, targetID, values) {
    ...
  }

  // init slider

  $(".noui-slider").each(function(index) {
    var sliderID = $(this).attr("id"),
        targetID = $(this).next().find(".slider-value").attr("id");
        values = $(this).data("slider");

    makeSlider(sliderID, targetID, values);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with current implementation it that the variable `value` doesn't refers to the defined array. Its a string literal having value i.e. *dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft*, *dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixRight*

Define the array in `window` or any other object scope.

```
// Matrix 1
window.dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft = [...];

// Matrix 2
window.dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixRight = [...]
```

Then use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object dynamic properties.

```
values = $(this).data("slider");
makeSlider(sliderID, targetID, window[values]);
```

An example here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myOBj = {};
    // slider array
    // Matrix 1
    myOBj.dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft = [{
        id: 1,
        value: "sehr wichtig"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        value: ""
    }, {
        id: 3,
        value: ""
    }, {
        id: 4,
        value: ""
    }, {
        id: 5,
        value: "unwichtig"
    }, {
        id: null,
        value: "weiß nicht"
    }];
    // Matrix 2
    myOBj.dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixRight = [{
        id: 1,
        value: "in hohem Maße"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        value: ""
    }, {
        id: 3,
        value: ""
    }, {
        id: 4,
        value: ""
    }, {
        id: 5,
        value: "in geringem Maße"
    }, {
        id: null,
        value: "weiß nicht"
    }];
    // build slider
    var makeSlider = function(sliderID, targetID, values) {
        console.log(values)
    }
    $(".noui-slider").on('click', function() {
        var values = $(this).data("slider");
        makeSlider(1, 2, myOBj[values]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='noui-slider' data-slider='dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft'>1</div>
<div class='noui-slider' data-slider='dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixRight'>2</div>
```

Comment: It is working! Thank you!

Is the "window" a special name? If I replace "window" with "arr", it does not work.

Comment: @user3852555, I have updated example snippet for clarity. You need to define a object i.e. `var myOBj = {};` then you can use it `myOBj.dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft = [...]` or `myOBj["dataMehrfachauswahlmatrixLeft"] = [....]`